# How to detect a key change in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write a query that assigns a group number to adjacent rows that share the same key value? I can't use a simple GROUP BY because the key could be used in multiple sets at different places in the result set.

For example, suppose that I want to compress these rows so that adjacent enrollment records for adjacent time periods can be compressed into a single enrollment record.

Here's some test data...

```
declare @enrollments table (
[Id] int not null identity(1,1),
[PlanCode] nvarchar(10) not null,       -- For simplicity, this is the key.
[BeginDate] int not null,
[EndDate] int null );

insert into @enrollments (PlanCode, BeginDate, EndDate) values 
     ('81-3', 20160101, null)
    ,('80-3', 20150701, 20160101)
    ,('80-3', 20150301, 20150701)
    ,('80-3', 20150101, 20150301)
    ,('80-1', 20140517, 20150101)
    ,('80-3', 20120906, 20140517)
    ,('80-1', 20120101, 20120906);

-- Source data.
select  *
from    @enrollments 
order by BeginDate desc;

-- Goal results.
select [Id] = 1, [PlanCode] = '81-3', [BeginDate] = 20160101, [EndDate] = NULL, [GroupNum] = 1
union
select [Id] = 2, [PlanCode] = '80-3', [BeginDate] = 20150701, [EndDate] = 20160101, [GroupNum] = 2
union
select [Id] = 3, [PlanCode] = '80-3', [BeginDate] = 20150301, [EndDate] = 20150701, [GroupNum] = 2
union
select [Id] = 4, [PlanCode] = '80-3', [BeginDate] = 20150101, [EndDate] = 20150301, [GroupNum] = 2
union
select [Id] = 5, [PlanCode] = '80-1', [BeginDate] = 20140517, [EndDate] = 20150101, [GroupNum] = 3
union
select [Id] = 6, [PlanCode] = '80-3', [BeginDate] = 20120906, [EndDate] = 20140517, [GroupNum] = 4
union
select [Id] = 7, [PlanCode] = '80-1', [BeginDate] = 20120101, [EndDate] = 20120906, [GroupNum] = 5;
```

So, give this data...

[image]

In its simplest form, I basically need to figure out how to determine the GroupNum. Once I have that I could GROUP BY and get the other aggregations that I need.

[image]

The date component of this means that "normal" grouping doesn't work. I'm really hoping there's a way to figure this out w/o using a cursor loop. I've been banging my head on this for a couple days now. It's time to phone a friend!

Thanks!
Ian

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention but this is on Azure Database.

Comment: The dupe applied to your data http://rextester.com/GZU90201