# Islands (Take #2)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have what I have learned through this forum is a "Gaps & Islands" problem. My [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810472/how-to-detect-a-key-change-in-sql-query?noredirect=1) referenced me to this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414603/change-number-column). However, I believe I have found a flaw in the existing question which I'm seeking to remedy.

Given this data & the query from the existing question...

```
declare @table table (
    [Name] varchar(20) not null,
    [Pay] int not null,
    [Date] date not null 
);

insert into @table values
 ('Sally', 10, '08/28/2012')
,('Sally', 12, '09/06/2012')
,('Sally', 10, '05/17/2014')
,('Sally', 12, '01/01/2015')
,('Sally', 13, '01/01/2016');

WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (
                    PARTITION BY [NAME]
                    ORDER BY DATE) - ROW_NUMBER()
                                       OVER (
                                         PARTITION BY [NAME], [PAY]
                                         ORDER BY DATE) AS [Grp]
         FROM   @table),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                MIN([DATE])
                  OVER (
                    PARTITION BY [NAME], [Grp]) AS [MinDate]
         FROM   T1)
SELECT [NAME],
       [PAY],
       [DATE],
       DENSE_RANK()
         OVER (
           PARTITION BY [NAME]
           ORDER BY [MinDate]) AS CHANGEGROUP
FROM   T2
ORDER  BY [NAME],
          [MinDate]
```

I would expect to get this result...

[image]

However, I get this...

[image]

So, it thinks that the consecutive Pay = 10 and Pay = 12 rows are on the same island which is incorrect. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Ian

Comment: If you run your T1 select only, what do you get for row numbers?

Comment: On Mobile but seems to fix it http://rextester.com/LGEA63875

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this other than the approach suggested by @MartinSmith. Use `lag` to get the previous Pay value and start a new group if it is different from the current row's Pay value in a running sum.

```
select name,pay,date
,sum(case when prev_pay=pay then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by name order by date) as change_group
from (select t.*,lag(pay) over(partition by name order by date) as prev_pay 
      FROM @table t
     ) t
```

Your query from the previous question would become

```
select id,plancode,begindate,enddate
,sum(case when prev_plan=plancode then 0 else 1 end) over(order by begindate desc) as grp
from (select e.*,lag(plancode) over(order by begindate desc) AS prev_plan 
      from @enrollments e
     ) t
```